# OctoberCMS. How to pass variable from page to component?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have defined a variable in a page:

```
{% set service = builderDetails.record  %}
```

and I want to pass this variable to a component:

```
{% component 'Variations' service=service %}
```

but this method does not work. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `{% component 'Variations' service = builderDetails.record %} `?

Comment: Also depends on where your trying to access it, https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#default-markup

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, i tried pass var to component template

Comment: Show the code your using, including the component onRender method. did you read that whole section in the link, it has an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you need to pass `builderDetails.record` to your `component 'Variations'`

and then you want to access that variables inside `component 'Variations'`'s  `default.htm` and show some details about it.

for that you need to utilize component's `onRender` method

inside your `component 'Variations'`

```
public function onRender()
{
     $this->page['record'] = $this->page->components['builderDetails']->record;
}
```

`$this->page->components` is holding all the components available in page as array.

`builderDetails` is alias of the component `Record Details`(Builder Plugin) which is added in to page.

now inside your `default.htm`

you can access `record` variable and use it as you desire

```
{{ record.name }}
```

> we assume here that your record has attribute `name`

if you need anything please comment.

Comment: Thanks it was really useful to see you could access other component's variables via `$this->page->components[''];` - Where is this documented btw ?

Comment: I actually seen while I was `debugging` stuff, so I learn it from there

Answer (score 0):

In a Twig .htm partial

```
<div class="sidebar-widget">
   {% component "postBlock" score=55 name="Johan" %}
   <div class="nonsense meta">
       {% partial 'nonsense' score=75 name="Marga" %}
   </div>
</div>
```

In the *nonsense* twig that is a child of the previous .htm partial

```
<div class="sidebar-element">
   <div>My name is: {{ name|default('John Doe') }}</div>
   <div>My score is: {{ score|default('No score') }}</div>
</div>
```

In the component *postBlock*, *onRender* function

```
function onRender() {
   $score = $this->property('score');  // 55
   $name = $this->property('name'); // Johan
}
```

To pass from a parent twig to a child twig, you don't have to use the *onRender* function
in the component, only if you want to modify things and pass is from there to the twig.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to assign it to page. You can access it via:

```
__SELF__.property('property_name')
```

After definin property in component:

```
{% component 'Variations' service=service %}
```

In your components default.htm

```
{{__SELF__.property('service')}}
```